# New PayPal Developer problems

Tags: paypal-sandbox

We are trying to test PayPal functionality in a dev environment but it has changed in the last few days and our "dev" login is no longer valid.

It looks like we now have to create sandbox accounts from within an actual registered business account. While this in itself is not a problem (annoying because we have to chase people around to set it up for us), the real problem is that you can't login to sandbox to place a test order without first being logged-in to PayPal Developers with our company's business account.

This is absolutely unacceptable... We, as developers, do not have access to the company's business account.

We also tried adding a user to the business account (with locked-down privileges), but it won't allow us to login to Developers with it.

Can someone please clarify the new process and how we can go about a) setting up sandbox accounts and b) placing test orders via PayPal's sandbox.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will have to create a live PayPal account in order to log in with your developer account. Once you log in with a PayPal account, you will see an option to import your previous developer account information from the 'application' tab.  If the business you are working with does not want to grant you access to log in, you will have to test using your own live account.

Once you have imported your sandbox account information, you should be able to log into any of your test accounts to make test purchases.

Comment: But to place an actual test order, I need to also be logged-in to the company's PayPal account?

Comment: You don't have to be logged in as the company, although you do have to log in initially with a live account. Once that is done you can do test purchases with your sandbox accounts. As an example I have to log into a live account (liveaccount@paypal.com), then log into one of my test account (testaccount@paypal.com) to make a test purchase. Hope this helps!

Comment: I'm not sure what a "live account" is. The only options I see in Developers is to log-in with an existing account, which would have to be the company's existing account, or to sign-up for a new business account which is for US companies only (we are in the UK).

I'm not happy with having to set-up a new "live account" for development purposes.

Comment: We already have an account but it belongs to the business and we, as developers, do not and cannot have access to it as it will violate a number of company policies. Are we to create another business account just for the purposes of testing?

Comment: That is what you would have to do if there is not a current business account that you are able to access. Guest login may be available in the future, but it is not an option at this time.

Comment: This is definitely a feature we need. I'm a bit confused by this decision by PayPal - since when did developers have full access to a payment provider's live accounts? I imagine we are not the first that will encounter this issue.

Comment: I completely understand your concerns as this is a commonly asked feature for PayPal sandbox. I work with the sandbox team regularly and I will pass along this feedback for you.

Comment: @Jared Please also convey this developer's absolute bafflement at this decision; the way it was carried out without prior notice; the fact that it clearly has bugs so was not adequately tested; and the way that it has caused a complete development outage for thousands of developers for several days. PayPal needs to start taking developers seriously. We are connecting our businesses to yours and do not need arbitrary disruptions in the process, or pointless new requirements on us either.